# Celery running tasks from synchronous queues

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-2.7, celery

Assume that I have periodic task that gets not processed messages from customers, and then runs tasks for processing those messages per user.
I can make router for this processing task so that process("customer1_msgs") will go to queue "customer1_queue" but then celery worker(/s) will get those tasks concurrently if they have free slot for processing. I dont want to process msgs for the same customer at the same time, is there are way to make workers do only one task per queue simultaneusly?

example flow:
periodic_task runs process("customer1_msgs"), process("customer2_msgs").
celery is processing customer2 and customer1(it can take long time)
then after some time periodic task will run again and run process("customer2_msgs"), process("customer3_msgs")
assuming that first process("customer2_msgs")is still processing messages, celery worker will start processing those tasks, and poof i have conflict with still running process("customer2_msgs") from first fetch of periodic task
(periodic task runs fast, processing msgs takes long time).

TL;DR version:
how to implement synchronous queues in celery? (tasks inside queue runs one after another, but other queues can also process tasks asynchronously(one task per queue))

Using python 2.7, django 1.4, celery(soon latest stable version), RabbitMQ message broker(, have also redis if needed) running on linux debian 7 wheezy

Comment: the easiest way i can think of is that have a single worker per queue

Comment: @dm03514 it could work if you have not many queues(/customers), but if there are many of them, and part of them is rarely active - its rather poor solution

Comment: I dont think this has anything to do with being synchronous. Your problem is that a same task might be processed twice at the same time. Celery does not handle such case, you have to do the proper handling yourself. The strategy of dealing with it depends on you. What do you want to do when two same tasks are on the queue? Drop one or wait for the completion?

Comment: @xbirkettx I think you didn't get what I'm after and your last question is negating yours first sentence, I want it to wait for completion(=being synchronous) in the same queue, eg. queueX has chained tasks process("customerX_msgs")

one periodic task gets all msgs, grouping them on customers, and make processing for those msgs per customer, but dont want to process the same customers msgs on the same time

Comment: I understood what you want, and as they already answered you, it cannot be done since celery does not have synchronous queues. I offered you a workaround to solve this problem which you mentioned "I dont want to process msgs for the same customer at the same time".